# Send variables in dynamically created buttons with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to send a variable to a function from dynamically created buttons (14 of them)

```
# creating buttons
    for i in range(0, 14):
        m_pauser.append(wx.Button(panel, 5, "Pause "+str(i)))
        m_pauser[i].Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: self.dispenser_pause(event, i), m_pauser[i])
        box.Add(m_pauser[i], 0, wx.ALL, 10)


# function called by buttons
    def dispenser_pause(self, event, my_value):
        print my_value
```

The problem is that all buttons always send 13 (the last value of 'i' in the 'for' loop)

How can I assign a value to a button so it sends it to the function? Is this the right way to make it work?

I just started with Python, so probably there's a lot that I'm missing out

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the issue is that every button gets the same ID, which seems to be `5` in your example. It is a bad habit to hardcode wxwidgets IDs. Use `-1` or `wx.NewId()` instead.

**EDIT**: It is not the ID (but ID they should be unique, anyway). The reason is that `i` does point to the last value it had (during the loop, `i` is always "the same thing" and there are never "distinct `i`'s). Do the following instead:

For the sake of clarity do can do the following:

```
m_pauser = []
for i in range(0, 14):
    btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Pause "+str(i))
    m_pauser.append(btn)
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event, temp=i: self.dispenser_pause(event, temp))
    box.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
```

The reason is explained better in [the wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks) than I could do it.