# Creating multiple buttons with for loop in wxpython causing problems

Tags: loops, user-interface, for-loop, lambda, wxpython

Good evening/morning,

I am writing a program in wxpython that repeats most of the code 4 times, and so I've been trying to shorten it. Here is one section that is not working though when I try to shorten it with a for loop:

```
# Handles the creation of all of the buttons
def make_button(text, callback, starty, startx, height, width):
    button = wx.Button(self, -1, text)
    sizer.Add(button, (starty, startx), (height, width), wx.EXPAND)
    button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, callback)
    return button

make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 1), 1, 2, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 2), 1, 7, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 3), 1, 12, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 4), 1, 17, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 1), 1, 3, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 2), 1, 8, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 3), 1, 13, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 4), 1, 18, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 1), 1, 4, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 2), 1, 9, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 3), 1, 14, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 4), 1, 19, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 1), 12, 1, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 2), 12, 6, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 3), 12, 11, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 4), 12, 16, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 1), 11, 1, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 2), 11, 6, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 3), 11, 11, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 4), 11, 16, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 1), 13, 1, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 2), 13, 6, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 3), 13, 11, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 4), 13, 16, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 1), 12, 2, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 2), 12, 7, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 3), 12, 12, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 4), 12, 17, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 1), 11, 2, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 2), 11, 7, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 3), 11, 12, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 4), 11, 17, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 1), 13, 2, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 2), 13, 7, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 3), 13, 12, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 4), 13, 17, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 1), 12, 3, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 2), 12, 8, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 3), 12, 13, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, 4), 12, 18, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 1), 11, 3, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 2), 11, 8, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 3), 11, 13, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, 4), 11, 18, 1, 1)

make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 1), 13, 3, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 2), 13, 8, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 3), 13, 13, 1, 1)
make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, 4), 13, 18, 1, 1)

def MarginLow(self, event, slot):
    print slot
def MarginHigh(self, event, slot):
    print slot
def MarginOff(self, event, slot):
    print slot
```

I was able to convert this code into a for loop like this:

```
# Create all of the margining buttons for each slot
for i in range(0, 4):
    # Global Rail commands for all 4 slots
    make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, i), 1, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, i), 1, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, i), 1, (i*5)+4, 1, 1)
    # Rail 1 for all 4 slots
    make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, i), 11, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, i), 12, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, i), 13, (i*5)+1, 1, 1)
    # Rail 2 for all 4 slots
    make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, i), 11, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, i), 12, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, i), 13, (i*5)+2, 1, 1)
    # Rail 3 for all 4 slots
    make_button("Margin High", lambda event: self.MarginHigh(event, i), 11, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)  
    make_button("Margin Low", lambda event: self.MarginLow(event, i), 12, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
    make_button("Margin Off", lambda event: self.MarginOff(event, i), 13, (i*5)+3, 1, 1)
```

The problem with the for loop is that for some reason, when I click the buttons and it goes to the definition and does the "print slot" command, it always prints out the highest value of my for loop. For example, my for loop goes from 0-3, so it always prints out 3, even if I click a button that was created during the first loop. If i change this higher or lower, it adjusts to match the last number.

So, why is it passing the position parameters fine but not the lambda event value i that should change for each loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send-variables-in-dynamically-created-buttons-with-wxpython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998340/send-variables-in-dynamically-created-buttons-with-wxpython).

Comment: yes, you are correct and that link did actually help me. Thanks!